# extracting attributes from html with lxml

Tags: python, html, lxml

I use `lxml` to retrieve the attributes of tags from an html page. The html page is formatted like this:

```
<div class="my_div">
    <a href="/foobar">
        <img src="my_img.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

The python script I use to retrieve the url inside the `<a>` tag and the `src` value of the `<img>` tag inside the same `<div>`, is this:

```
from lxml import html 

...
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
for element in tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "my_div")]//a'):
    href = element.xpath('/@href')
    src = element.xpath('//img/@src')
```

Why don't I get the strings?

Answer (score 10):

You are using lxml so you are operating with lxml objects - HtmlElement instances.
HtmlElement is nested from etree.Element: http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html,
it have ***get*** method, that returns attrubute value.
So the proper way for you is:

```py
from lxml import html 

...
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
for link_element in tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "my_div")]//a'):
    href = link_element.get('href')
    image_element = href.find('img')
    if image_element:
        img_src = image_element.get('src')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change your code to:

```
from lxml import html 

...
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
for element in tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "my_div")]//a'):
    href = element.items()[0][1]  #gives you the value corresponding to the key "href"
    src = element.xpath('//img/@src')[0]
    print(href, src)
```

You'll get what you need.

The [documentation of `lxml`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html) mentions some of these things, but I feel it is lacking a few things and you might want to consider using an interactive python shell to study the properties of the instances returned by `tree.xpath()`. Or you could look into another parser completely, such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), which has very good examples and documentation. Just sharing...

Comment: I do agree and disagree, **lxml** might not be the best for xpath handling, however above all, it's a very easy to use, fast and robust html/xml parser. **BeautifulSoup** doesn't come with a parser itself, it uses Python standard library (which is comparably slower than **lxml**), but can be configured to use 3rd party like **lxml**, even their doc suggests installing **lxml** for speed. But I do agree that **BeautifulSoup** is rather well documented and easy to learn.

Comment: @Anzel, I agree with everything you said. Indeed, BeautifulSoup mentions that lxml is a fast library and should not be overlooked. It's just that documentation, often the best source of examples, plays a big part in a library's adoption by the community. Point in case: the amount of BeautifulSoup tagged questions vs those tagged lxml (~2/1).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you didn't get the results you want is because you're trying to get attributes from the **NEXT** children rather than the existing node.

See this:

```
from lxml import html

s = '''<div class="my_div">
    <a href="/foobar">
        <img src="my_img.png">
    </a>
</div>'''

tree = html.fromstring(s)

# when you do path... //a, you are ALREADY at 'a' node
for el in tree.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "my_div")]//a'):
    # you were trying to get next children /@href, which doesn't exist
    print el.xpath('@href') # you should instead access the existing node's 
    print el.xpath('img/@src') # same here, not /img/@src ...

['/foobar']
['my_img.png']
```

Hope this helps.